# How to upload an image to IBM Cloud object storage (COS) using Node.js?

Tags: amazon-s3, ibm-cloud, object-storage, cloud-object-storage

I am using **ibm-cos-sdk** but I can able to store text files only, but I want to upload images and pdf files. Can someone help me out of that?

Answer (score 0):

The IBM Cloud solution tutorial on how to [apply end to end security to a cloud app](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/solution-tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-cloud-e2e-security) features a file sharing app. The files are stored in COS, the [app built using Node.js](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/secure-file-storage). [See these lines of code for the example](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/secure-file-storage/blob/master/app.js#L202).

```
  // upload to COS
  await cos.upload({
    Bucket: COS_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: `${fileDetails.userId}/${fileDetails.id}/${fileDetails.name}`,
    Body: fs.createReadStream(file.path),
    ContentType: fileDetails.type,
  }).promise();
```

The snippet uses the mentioned **ibm-cos-sdk** with the **S3** interface. I have used the app and code to upload images and PDFs.